# rails rabl multiple collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, collections, rabl

I'm having a bit of trouble with `rabl`. This code

```
collection favourite_groups, root: :groups

extends 'favourites/base'
```

gives me the following json structure: `{ groups: [ {..}, {..} ] }`. What I need is to append another node that contains an array - `{ groups: [ {..}, {..} ], users: [ {..}, {..} ] }` The data is in separate variables, but it can be in one, which ever makes this work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, nevermind, made it work with this

```
object false

child favourite_groups => :groups do
  collection favourite_groups
  extends 'favourites/base'
end

child favourite_users => :users do
  collection favourite_users
  extends 'favourites/base'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late for an anwser
I did try you syntax but didn't work for me :
I think if you append a child with no record, this will confuse rabl engine, because it's looking for a descendent of the root object
I did replace with a node element and a partial and it works

```
object false # ok, no record

node :favourite_groups => :groups do
   partial('favourites.json.rabl', :object => @favourite_groups) 
end

node :favourite_users => :users do
  partial('favourites.json.rabl', :object => @favourite_users)
end
```

There is an explanation what are the differences between node and child [Github rabl Tips and tricks](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Tips-and-tricks)

Hope this help

Comment: In this case you present, you do actually render an object. when I needed an array. in your case i think the following should work `child :favourite_users => :users { |users| extends 'users/base' }` it really does depend on your use case. from my understanding `child` nodes change the `local[:object]`. methods `attributes` now relate to the 'child' object.